# What's the best way to insert multiple rows in postgres from multithreaded Python application using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with postgres. Sometimes (on the highest request frequency) `UniqueViolation` exception is raising when I'm trying to insert rows in table.

Here's the part of my code:

```
class Prediction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "predictions"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    # and much more columns

# ...

db = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

# ...

def predict(image_id: int, image_key: str):
    result = detector.detect(image_key, classes)

    for i in result:
        db_prediction = models.Prediction(
            # pass all params except id
        )
        db.add(db_prediction)
    db.commit()  # exception raising at this line
```

I understand that problem is in non-unique value of `id` column in rows I'm trying to insert. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to catch exceptions like this and insert row(s), not loosing function results.

I know about `rollback()`, but how to use it with `try ... catch` and insert row with correct id?

UPD: Traceback of exception:

```
[2024-03-14 14:13:13,222: ERROR/MainProcess] Task project.worker.gpu_worker.predict_local[7cb690c2-bfc0-483f-943f-ffc673b68875] raised unexpected: IntegrityError('(psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "predictions_pkey"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(13) already exists.\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1970, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 924, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "predictions_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(13) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/neurospector/worker/gpu_worker.py", line 54, in predict_local
    db.commit()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1972, in commit
    trans.commit(_to_root=True)
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1257, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "<string>", line 2, in _prepare_impl
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1232, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4296, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4431, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4392, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 466, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 642, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 93, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1048, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection.execute(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1421, in execute
    return meth(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 514, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1643, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1849, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1989, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2356, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1970, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 924, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "predictions_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(13) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO predictions (id, image_id, x1, y1, x2, y2, class_id, confidence) VALUES (%(id)s, %(image_id)s, %(x1)s, %(y1)s, %(x2)s, %(y2)s, %(class_id)s, %(confidence)s)]
[parameters: {'id': 13, 'image_id': 5727, 'x1': 852.0, 'y1': 136.0, 'x2': 964.0, 'y2': 534.0, 'class_id': 1, 'confidence': 0.264892578125}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
```

SQLAlchemy version is `2.0.28`

DDL of table:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: predictions; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE TABLE public.predictions (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    image_id integer,
    x1 integer,
    y1 integer,
    x2 integer,
    y2 integer,
    class_id integer,
    confidence double precision
);


ALTER TABLE public.predictions OWNER TO user;

--
-- Name: predictions_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.predictions_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.predictions_id_seq OWNER TO user;

--
-- Name: predictions_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

ALTER SEQUENCE public.predictions_id_seq OWNED BY public.predictions.id;


--
-- Name: predictions id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.predictions ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.predictions_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: predictions predictions_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.predictions
    ADD CONSTRAINT predictions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: ix_predictions_class_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE INDEX ix_predictions_class_id ON public.predictions USING btree (class_id);


--
-- Name: ix_predictions_confidence; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE INDEX ix_predictions_confidence ON public.predictions USING btree (confidence);


--
-- Name: ix_predictions_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_predictions_id ON public.predictions USING btree (id);


--
-- Name: ix_predictions_image_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

CREATE INDEX ix_predictions_image_id ON public.predictions USING btree (image_id);


--
-- Name: predictions predictions_class_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.predictions
    ADD CONSTRAINT predictions_class_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES public.classes(id);


--
-- Name: predictions predictions_image_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.predictions
    ADD CONSTRAINT predictions_image_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES public.images(id);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: I doubt this is the whole relevant code. You have `id` column set as `autoincrement` so it's **very** unlikely for this situation happen as this feature is exactly for the purpose and RDBMS is ready to handle that properly. Are you sure you are not having any other column comfigured as `unique`? If so that most likely would be your real problem if the values are not unique, not the `id`.

Comment: Totally sure that only `id` is unique. So the only answer is embrace db interaction lines with `try ... except`?

Comment: `try`/`catch` won't hurt but you will be fixing things in blind. Not understand the problem first leads to going down the [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) path, which is quite ineffective. Can you please post the whole stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Please post the version of SQLAlchemy and the `DDL`  of your table. New versions use `identity` which is absolute prove against duplication of the key column. See [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-10-and-above-identity-columns) how to configure *identity* column.

Comment: Updated post, please check new info

Comment: The traceback shows that you _are_ passing `id` (the parameter dict at the bottom is generated by SQLAlchemy, not PostgreSQL).

Comment: Your sequence is only a `DEFAULT` option and you pass the *id* in the insert: `SQL: INSERT INTO predictions (id,` ... `parameters: {'id': 13`. Pls check the link above how to configure an *identity* column correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Marmite Bomber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4808122/marmite-bomber) and [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) for their comments, that's the answer:

```
class Prediction(Base):
__tablename__ = "predictions"

id = Column("id", Integer, Identity(start=1, cycle=False), primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
```

The catch was that I expected `autoincrement` to do what `Identity` does